# getting runtime error assembly 'System.Runtime' while using CSharpCodeProvider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, csharpcodeprovider

I'm getting runtime error about missing reference.

> The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I'm using MVC application and used CSharpCodeProvider inside my code.

I do not get any compile error but getting runtime error for `compileResult` as above why?

```
 CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
```

I even added `assemblies` tag in `web.cofig` like following still same error.any clue why?

```
  <assemblies>     
    <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />   
  </assemblies>
```

Comment: Have you explicitly added the reference to the assembly? Removed and re-added?

Comment: Please see this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660999/the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-how-to-find-the-cause

This should resolve your problem

Comment: @Chander.k unable to get this answer ? can you specifically elaborate for my problem ?

Comment: What is the code you are compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC uses the `dynamic` keyword a lot. That may be the original of the problem, since that requires both the `Microsoft.CSharp` assembly (which you have obviously included) and the `System.Runtime` assembly (I think this one is missing.

Add the `System.Runtime` assembly in your compile config:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll"); // guess you have this one already
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Runtime.dll");
```

Comment: this resolved my specific system runtime dll error but i wonder why this is not resolved when I have added it in web.config?

Comment: Because compiling the code has nothing to do with your currently running code. You need to tell the compiler how to compile.

Comment: that is why it does not read it from web.config you mean to say?

Comment: Indeed. Why should it? What if you want to compile for another version of the assembly?

Comment: cool great thanks a lot, actually everywhere only web.config tag solution is given thanks :)