# Accessing base class variables C#

Tags: c#

I have base class

```
public class X
{
   public int Id;
   public int i;
}
```

and derived class

```
public class Y : X
{

//other variables

}
```

I have 3 projects in my solution. Class X is in project A, class Y in project B, and in project C I am trying to do:

```
Y newY = new Y();
newY. // this is where no variables from base class are showed (no Id or i)
```

If I reference project A from project C, it works. But can I do it without referencing project A from C?

Existing references are : B -> A and
                          C -> B

Comment: he said each class in separate DLL and use different DLL to use Y class and there is no intellisense

Comment: you'll absolutely need a c=>a reference; with nuget package references it may now be transitive ; anything else, you'll need to be explicit

Comment: If you want to access `Class X` in `Project A` from `Project C` you _must_ have a reference from `Project C -> Project A`. If you have `Project B -> Project A` and `Project C -> Project B`, Visual Studio may have added `Project C -> Project A` behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you explain why is that? Because as far as I can see all I am using in `Project C` is a Class from `Project B` and I have referenced `Project B` from `Project C`?

Comment: Because the definition of X, you could say its metadata, is on `Project A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Project B` does required reference `Project A` as class Y is derived from class X and some of the parent functionalities are written in `Project A` only.

so adding reference of only `ProjectB` (not `ProjectA`) in your mail project, and trying to call functionalities of `ProjectB` will surely fail in compile time.

like below.

```
//of Project A
public class X
{
    public string XStr;
    public void MethodOfX()
    {
        
    }
}
```

and

```
// of Prject B
public class Y : X
{
    public string YStr;
    public void MethodOfY()
    {
        //values form Project A is available
        // as assembly reference has added here
        YStr = XStr;
        MethodOfX();
    }
}
```

you can see, here you can access properties of class x too. as reference of `ProjectA` has been added in `ProjectB`.

and in main class. by adding reference of `ProjectB` only, if we try following.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Y y = new Y();
        y.MethodOfY();
    }
```

on `Y y = new Y()` we will get this error on compile,

> The type 'ProjectA.X' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ProjectA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Here error is self explanatory. it simply state that for doing `Y y = new Y()` you will required to deal with `ProjectA.X` (here in our case it is because we are inheriting it) and assembly which is having definition of `ProjectA.X` is not yet referenced in main project.

have a look in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660999/the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-how-to-find-the-cause)

As here we are having `Y` inheriting `X` we need to add reference of `ProjectA` too in our main project because in this case `Y` is holding some functionalities which is defined in `ProjectA`.

*And as we haven't added `ProjectA`'s reference in our main project where we are trying to create object of Y, that object will not able to expose Y's those functionalities and members which are defined in `ProjectA`*

---

but if we change our code like below.

```
//of Project A
public class X
{
    public string XStr;
    public void MethodOfX()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method of x");
    }
}
```

and

```
// of Prject B
public class Y 
{
    public string YStr;
    public void MethodOfY()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method of Y");
        X x = new X();
        //values form Project A is available
        // as assembly reference has added here
        YStr = x.XStr;
        x.MethodOfX();
    }
}
```

Note that now Y is not inheriting X, but simply creates an instance of X and using it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Y y = new Y();
            y.MethodOfY();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

in our main project even after adding reference of only `ProjectB` and not `ProjectA`, above code will not cause any exception. because here while creating object of `Y` main project doesn't need to deal with `ProjectA` as all functionlities and members of Y are in `projectB` only.

And while calling the method `MethodOfY()` even if that method internally calls method of x too, this calls will be handled if dll of `ProjectA` is present in Application's run path (if you are debugging, usually in Debug folder).

**Note:** if dll of ProjectA is not there by any circumstances it will throw an exeption while calling `MethodOfY()` saying that it cannot load `ProjectA` dll (of course becuase it was not present there)