# Error CS0012 when building for Android in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've got my game ready to go yet and I encounter CS0012 error upon building.

```
error CS0012: The type 'UnityEngine.MonoBehavior' is defined 
in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly 
'UnityEngine, Version=0.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyTiken=null'
```

I'm using Unity 2018.1.9f1, building for Android 8.0 using Scripting Runtime Version .NET 4.x Equivalent, Scripting Backend is Mono and API compatibility level is .NET 4.x

Comment: Hello Waro. Good question for your first post. I have make some formatting in adding new lines and I have replaced your picture by the error message because it is always more clear to put directly the information in StackOverflow site. You can view my change in editing your post again.

Comment: What does the error mean? What should I do

Comment: Hello Waro. Sorry but I don't know Unity. I'm a simpl user that has gained the right to monitor first question of new user. I very only that your question is correct and well formatted.

Comment: But, I'm VB.Net developper and I think that you have forgotten to add UnityEngine assembly in REFERENCE part of your project. This link can perhaps help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660999/the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-how-to-find-the-cause

Comment: or in following link from Microsfot with title: Using .NET 4.x in Unity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2017