# Why do I get "The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" in this case?

Tags: c#

Consider the following situation which results in:

> The type 'ConnectionStringSettingsCollection' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Configuration, Version ...'.

**Assembly A.dll:**

```
// References System.Configuration

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int value)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ConnectionStringSettingsCollection is defined in System.Configuration
    public Foo(ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connString)  
    { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Assembly B.dll:**

```
// References A.dll and _not_ System.Configuration

public class Bar
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        var aFoo = new Foo(3); // Complains
    }
}
```

The line `var aFoo = new Foo(3);` complains with the error message mentioned above, which is clear and understandable.

However I don't understand, why I have to reference `System.Configuration` in assembly `B.dll` when the type isn't publicly *exposing* any property nor has any method which returns anything of that type.

Comment: have you added the corresponding using statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced, how to find the cause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660999/the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-how-to-find-the-cause)

Comment: The C# compiler needs to decide which particular constructor overload is most appropriate.  It insists on knowing everything about them, can't do that when it doesn't know what a ConnectionStringSettingsCollection might be.  You could consider whether that constructor should be internal or a factory method is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

> the type isn't publicly exposing any property nor has any method which returns anything of that type

This is not really true. The `Foo` type has a public constructor which expects that type as its argument:

```
public Foo(ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connString)
```

hence it is part of the type's (and the assembly's) public contract. In the `B` assembly the compiler needs to understand this contract *in full*, so that it is able to resolve and call the right methods, properties, constructors etc.

Comment: Calling new Foo(3) isn't allowed but calling new Foo(value: 3) is. The compiler can easily infer that 3 is of type int whether named arguments are used or not. There must be another reason.

Comment: @JessRod No, it cannot _that_ easily. Custom implicit conversion operators may come into play. When the explicit argument name `value` is used, it disambiguates the situation.