# How to Draw a Line with Six Labors ImageSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, imagesharp

Using Six Labors ImageSharp 1.0.4 for .Net core, how can I draw a line between two points? My code below combines three images into the `GridImage` and then I want to draw a line on the new image.

When I call `imageContext.DrawLines(linePen, points)` I am getting the error:

> The type IImageProcessingContext<> is defined in a reference that is not referenced to assembly Sixlabors.ImageSharp.

However, I am referencing SixLabors in the using statement.

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
using System;
using System.IO;

public void CombineImagesDrawLine() {
    using (Image<Rgba32> img1 = Image.Load<Rgba32>("gridTemplate.png"))
    using (Image<Rgba32> img2 = Image.Load<Rgba32>("circleOne.png"))
    using (Image<Rgba32> img3 = Image.Load<Rgba32>("circleTwo.png"))

    using (Image<Rgba32> GridImage = new Image<Rgba32>(1024, 576)) // create output image of the correct dimensions
    {
        // take img1 and img2 and draw them onto the image
        GridImage.Mutate(o => o
            .DrawImage(img1, new Point(0, 0), 1f)
            .DrawImage(img2, new Point(100, 100), 1f) 
        );

        // Add img3
        GridImage.Mutate(o => o
            .DrawImage(img3, new Point(200, 250), 1f)
        );

        GridImage.Mutate(imageContext =>
        {
            var points = new SixLabors.Primitives.PointF[2];
            points[0] = new SixLabors.Primitives.PointF(
                x: (float)(89),
                y: (float)(118));
            points[1] = new SixLabors.Primitives.PointF(
                x: (float)(901),
                y: (float)(379));

            var lineColor = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color.FromRgb(
                r: (byte)124,
                g: (byte)190,
                b: (byte)75);
            float lineWidth = 5;

            var linePen = new Pen(lineColor, lineWidth);                     

            imageContext.DrawLines(linePen, points); // !!This is where my code fails
     }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced, how to find the cause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660999/the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-how-to-find-the-cause)

Comment: I saw that post yesterday during my troubleshooting and it didn't help. I am confused on this one, but I feel like I need to create a class reference. Here is the documentation for this class and method https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp.Drawing/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing.Processing.DrawLineExtensions.html

Answer (score 1):

The error is stating `Sixlabors.ImageSharp` is referencing another assembly that your project is missing.

The Github samples for Sixlabors shows [these references in the .csproj](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp.Drawing/blob/423bf06a6b8bfce3a9991bede8af3e550c6742ca/src/ImageSharp.Drawing/ImageSharp.Drawing.csproj):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.Fonts" Version="1.0.0-beta15" />
  <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="1.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And looking at the [dependencies in Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing/) for `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing`:

```
.NETCoreApp 2.1
SixLabors.Fonts (>= 1.0.0-beta15)
SixLabors.ImageSharp (>= 1.0.3)

.NETCoreApp 3.1
SixLabors.Fonts (>= 1.0.0-beta15)
SixLabors.ImageSharp (>= 1.0.3)

.NETFramework 4.7.2
SixLabors.Fonts (>= 1.0.0-beta15)
SixLabors.ImageSharp (>= 1.0.3)

.NETStandard 1.3
NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.1)
SixLabors.Fonts (>= 1.0.0-beta15)
SixLabors.ImageSharp (>= 1.0.3)

.NETStandard 2.0
SixLabors.Fonts (>= 1.0.0-beta15)
SixLabors.ImageSharp (>= 1.0.3)

.NETStandard 2.1
SixLabors.Fonts (>= 1.0.0-beta15)
SixLabors.ImageSharp (>= 1.0.3)
```

If you're not using Nuget to pull the package down, then try removing the current reference and then re-referencing with the Nuget package.

Otherwise, remove the current SixLabors reference and then grab the [latest Release from SixLabors](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp.Drawing/releases), and add to your project.

Finally, be sure to read the [SixLabors installation documentation](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp.Drawing#installation).

Comment: I have tried multiple times to get the package references correct, but it isn't cooperating after going through the documentation multiple times. I have gone to another solution for imaging. GrapeCity's GcDocuments for Imaging. There is a cost, but works great!

Comment: @launchCode have you tried creating the most basic of projects following their guidance / walk throughs? If you can get that to run, then you should be able to figure out why your actual project is failing.

Comment: I've just had a similar problem - needed to tick "Include prerelease" in the Nuget Package Manager to see the beta version of `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing`. After that the [blog I was following](https://swharden.com/csdv/platforms/imagesharp/) worked perfectly.